# whisper AI error : FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, openai-api, openai-whisper

I'm trying to use whisper AI on my computer. I have a NVIDIA GPU RTX 2060, installed CUDA and FFMPEG.

I'm running this code :

```
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("medium")
result = model.transcribe("venv/files/test1.mp3")
print(result["text"])
```

and having issue :

```
whisper\transcribe.py:114: UserWarning: FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead
  warnings.warn("FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead")
```

I don't understand why FP16 is not support since I have a good GPU and everything installed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I installed all the requirement and I was expecting that whisper AI would use the GPU

Answer (score 9):

You could try this:

```
result = model.transcribe("venv/files/test1.mp3", fp16=False)
```

That helps me!

Comment: Wouldn't that just turn off the error message, without fixing anything?  He wants FP16, you suggest setting it to false.

Answer (score 2):

In order to utilize `CUDA` with `whisper`, you have to:

1. Uninstall existing `pytorch`.
2. Install `pytorch` with `CUDA`.
3. Load `pytorch` library
4. Add a chained call to `to` method after original `load_model`.

**Full example**

`Terminal`

```
pip3 uninstall -y torch torchvision torchaudio
# following command was generated using https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#with-cuda-1
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

`file.py`

```
import torch
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
whisper.load_model('medium').to(device)
```